# Change progress description for seekbar (float to int conversion)

Tags: android, type-conversion, android-progressbar

I must have to use 0 to 300 for a seekbar for min and maxvalue respectively.

But to show its progress in a textView between -15 to 15.

```
-15(seekmin)------------0(middle)---------------15(seekmax)

 0(seekmin)-------------150(middle)-----------300(seekmax)
```

I code it like

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2)
{
    int val = Math.round((float) (progress/10.0)) -15;

    eqTextView[i].setText(String.valueOf(progress));

    Log.e("SeekTest", "ing  " + progress + "VAL is" + val);
}
```

**val should show -15 to 15  but it is showing -15 to 285. I know my logic is correct but problem converting it to int.**

Comment: eqTextView[i].setText(String.valueOf(val)); ?

Comment: I know but i am testing it in Log. @Vishnudev K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of rewriting your onProgressChanged method. I haven't tested it, but this should work.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar , int progress , boolean arg2)
{

   float ratio = (float)progress / (float)seekBar.getMax();

   int fromMinus15ToPlus15 = Math.round(ratio * 30 - 15);
   int fromZeroTo300 = Math.round(ratio * 300);

   eqTextView[i].setText(String.valueOf(fromMinus15ToPlus15));

   Log.e("SeekTest", "ing  " + progress + "VAL is" + fromMinus15ToPlus15);
}
```

Comment: Now if i want to change back to 0 to 300 . What to do then. Please.

Comment: My solution is more expandable, since it doesn't rely on some hard-coded value for the max-value of the seekbar, and rather simply creates a between 0-to-1 value of the progress. Once you have that, you can easily use this value to convert any limit you like: totalRange * ratio - startingValue.

Comment: You could also use: (MaxValue - MinValue) * ratio - MinValue